# javascript regex match tag like html

Tags: javascript, regex

Because, I don't have much experience about regex. In my case, I want to get content in `<text>` tag and `<music>` tag int the below string. The result will be 2 array is below also:

The string to match:

`"<text>Chủ nhật, ngày 24 tháng 5 năm 1863, giáo sư Lidenbrockenbrock vội vã trở về ngôi nhà của ông ở số 19 đường Konigstasse, nằm trong khu phố cổ kính nhất ở thành phố Hambourg.</text><music>abc.wav</music>"`

Result:

`["Chủ nhật, ngày 24 tháng 5 năm 1863, giáo sư Lidenbrockenbrock vội vã trở về ngôi nhà của ông ở số 19 đường Konigstasse, nằm trong khu phố cổ kính nhất ở thành phố Hambourg."]`

and

["abc.wav"]

Answer (score -1):

Arrays in result are required? In the following code, you can get the content you want except for arrays. If you want arrays just wrap the content.

```
/**
 * If <music> always follows <text>
 */
var matches = /<text>([\s\S]+?)<\/text>\s*<music>([\s\S]+?)<\/music>/.exec(STRING_TO_MATCH);
var text, music;
if (matches) {
    text = matches[0]; // <text> content
    music = matches[1]; // <music> content
}

/**
 * Otherwise 
 */
var text = /<text>([\s\S]+?)<\/text>/.exec(STRING_TO_MATCH);
var music = /<music>([\s\S]+?)<\/music>/.exec(STRING_TO_MATCH);
if (text) text = text[0];
if (music) music = music[0];
```

Comment: thank you so much for respond my question. But It doesn't work when the string have line break `\r\n`.

Answer (score -1):

Because, the code from @taggon is not work when the string have line break suck as `\r\n`. So I added one line before it. It will be fine:

```
STRING_TO_MATCH = STRING_TO_MATCH.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>');

/**
 * If <music> always follows <text>
 */
var matches = /<text>(.+?)<\/text>\s*<music>(.+?)</music>/.exec(STRING_TO_MATCH);
var text, music;
if (matches) {
    text = matches[0]; // <text> content
    music = matches[1]; // <music> content
}

/**
 * Otherwise 
 */
var text = /<text>(.+?)<\/text>/.exec(STRING_TO_MATCH);
var music = /<music>(.+?)<\/music>/.exec(STRING_TO_MATCH);
if (text) text = text[0];
if (music) music = music[0];
```